# Generating service class from discovery file of iOS

Tags: ios, google-cloud-endpoints

I have a discovery file in rpc format but using a new generator I can't generate it.

How can I generate the file for iOS using new service generator?

Answer (score 0):

You need to get a REST format discovery file.